# Copy Multiple Rows into Single Column in another sheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

I have this huge date of Activity of various process which looks like this.

[image]

I need output like this.
 [image]

and i try to use this bellow Macro.

```
Sub lrow()
 Dim lcol As Long, rw As Long, j As Long, rc As Range
 j = 1
      For rw = 2 to Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      For lcol = 2 to Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        set rc = Cells(rw, lcol)
          If IsDate(rc.Value) Then
           With Sheet2
             Range(j, 2) = rc.Value
             j = j + 1
           End With
          End If
      Next lcol
      Next rw
  End Sub
```

I need help on this Code pls. thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain what isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a **serpentine** transfer:

```
Sub Serpentine()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long, j As Long
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
   K = 1
   Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To N
      For j = 1 To Columns.Count
         If sh1.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
            sh2.Cells(K, 1).Value = sh1.Cells(i, j).Value
            K = K + 1
         Else
            Exit For
         End If
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

For example in *Sheet1*:

[image]

Will produce in *Sheet2*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with a solution if you're not telling us what the problem is, but here's my stab at it. No need for a double-nested loop; just walk over all input cells until you reach an empty one, then jump to the beginning of the next line:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    While rng.Column > 1 Or Not IsEmpty(rng)
        Debug.Print rng.Value
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1)
        If IsEmpty(rng) Then Set rng = ws.Cells(rng.Row + 1, 1)
    Wend
End Sub
```

The loop halts when it encounters an empty cell in the first column. You'll notice I didn't bother to write the dates to a second worksheet, but that's trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This code is effectively taking all dates from the first sheet and pasting them in the A column of Sheet 2:

```
Sub lrow()

j As Long, rc As Range

j = 1

For Each rc In Sheets(1).Range("A1", Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
    If IsDate(rc.Value) Then
        With Worksheets(2)
             .Cells(j, 1) = rc.Value
             j = j + 1
        End With
    End If
Next rc


End Sub
```

Don't know if that's what you want.